# How to set a footer dynamically in a print html file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, printing

I have a print HTML file.

I can set the footer using CSS/SCSS like this:

```
@page {
  @bottom-center {content: "Copyright AMCE Pty Ltd";}
}
```

Problem is, CSS/SCSS are static. The Ruby On Rails pipeline compiles them once on production when you push them to the server.

How can I set a different footer for each HTML print document using Rails?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to an attribute value:

```
@page {
    @bottom-center { div.my_placeholder {content: attr(data-footer-text);} }
}
```

The actual text is the value of the `data-footer-text` attribute. The `div` element serves the only purpose of carrying the attribute containing the daat to print.

Of course, this approach will only work if your application can modify the html accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Do I also have to set display on my_placeholder on hidden to stop it appearing in the body of my print outs as well as the margin?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I couldn't get it to work. However, I did solve the problem for myself by inserting a small internal stylesheet into the HTML (which is dynamically generated) in addition to the main style sheet (which is static)